# Ruby on Rails error ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[this is what I get when I run the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB9si.png)
Hi, I'm working on a project. 
When I run my project, I got this problem:
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

```
bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
 raise ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?
```

(connection)

I've already tried several solutions below:

1)

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

2) `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

3) `bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

but they didn't work, and I got the same error over and over again.
What can I do?

Comment: An approach I think I used once was to delete the schema.rb and run the `rake db:migrate` command. I couldn't reproduce the error, hence the reason I've not been able to post it on Rails Issues

Comment: which database you are using ?

Comment: I would suggest to stop the server and run the first step that you have tried previosuly (Drop, create and migrate) and then restart.

Comment: @Hara Jang did you try any of the suggested solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first try was close, you need to do

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:schema:load
```

Check this article it may be helpful.
http://icebergist.com/posts/rake-db-migrate-vs-rake-db-schema-load/

Answer (score 1):

```
$ rm db/schema.rb
$ bundle exec rake db:drop
$ bundle exec rake db:create
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just rake db:reset. That always works for me, when I get stuck.

Comment: I doubt if you can do a db:reset. This will completely clear the data in the database. This is what happens when you have an existing database to connect.